# Flex String to XML

Tags: xml, apache-flex, string

I have a string in XML format and I want to use this string as flex XML type as following :

This is my string :

```
<Graph>
   <Node id="1" name="1" nodeColor="0x333333" nodeIcon="center" x="10" y="10" />
   <Node id="2" name="2" nodeColor="0x333333" nodeIcon="center" x="10" y="10" />
   <Node id="3" name="3" nodeColor="0x333333" nodeIcon="center" x="10" y="10" />
</Graph>
```

I cant pass this to an API, it complains that this is string and it expects an XML type. How can i convert this string to XML with minimum effort, ie: without iterating the string and the nodes etc. Is there such method as : var data:XML = new XML(str:String);

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This blog entry](http://www.mindlence.com/WP/?p=289) suggests that the following would work:

```
var sText:String = "<your-xml-here />";
var xData:XML    = XML(sText);
```

Comment: interesting, i thought of that, but didnt try it as you can see in the question. i ll try now.

Comment: You could also change the last line to
xData = sText as XML;

Answer (score 4):

To add to Tomalak's comment, you could also simply define:

```
var xData:XML = <Graph>
                   <Node id="1" name="1" nodeColor="0x333333" nodeIcon="center" x="10" y="10" />
                   <Node id="2" name="2" nodeColor="0x333333" nodeIcon="center" x="10" y="10" />
                   <Node id="3" name="3" nodeColor="0x333333" nodeIcon="center" x="10" y="10" />
                </Graph>;
```